Github does not compare to the correct branch
I'm working on a fork of a collaborative project. To be clear, I have the collaborative project (upstream), my remote fork (origin) and my local version of the fork (local). I'll call the different branch using a ':'.
I've create a remote branch called origin:develop-upstream by using github "New branch" from the source upstream:develop. However, origin:develop-upstream is comparing itself to upstream:main instead of upstream:develop.
In this way, I get this message which annoys me :
This branch is 18 commits ahead of, 4 commits behind upstream:main.

I would expect it to be : This branch is 0 commit ahead or behind of upstream:develop.
I've looked at the documentation but can't figure out what is wrong with my git project. Is this a problem with github itself ?

After more research, I think it is not a feature of github to choose the branch it compares to. The only way to change it is to have the same name between upstream and origin. So for example, origin/dev will compares to upstream/dev if upstream/dev exists. Else, it will compare to upstream/main (or the default branch).

You are right, since a fork is just a bare copy of the upstream repo, it will compare and sync branches by name.

Thanks, if you write post this comment, I'll add it as an answer since it isn't possible to fix it by any other mean than changing the branch name to actually match.

That is not possible.
Since a fork is just a bare copy of the upstream repo, it will compare and sync branches by name.
